# How to have new User in admin page after email confirmation?

Tags: python, html, django, admin

How to solve the problem whenever someone registers in my site, before email confirmation, it should not be added in admin page. But it is adding before email confirmation.

**views.py**

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save(commit=False)
            user.is_active = False
            user.save()
            current_site = get_current_site(request)
            mail_subject = 'Activate your Account.'
            message = render_to_string('users/active_email.html', {
                'user': user,
                'domain': current_site.domain,
                'uid':urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)),
                'token':account_activation_token.make_token(user),
            })
            to_email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
            email = EmailMessage(
                        mail_subject, message, to=[to_email]
            )
            email.send()
            return render(request, 'users/confirm_email.html')
    else:
        form = UserRegisterForm()
    return render(request, 'users/register.html', {'form': form})

def activate(request, uidb64, token):
    try:
        uid = force_text(urlsafe_base64_decode(uidb64))
        user = User.objects.get(pk=uid)
    except(TypeError, ValueError, OverflowError, User.DoesNotExist):
        user = None
    if user is not None and account_activation_token.check_token(user, token):
        user.is_active = True
        user.save()
        return render(request, 'users/confirmed_email.html')
    return HttpResponse('Activation link is invalid!')
```

**admin.py**

```
class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_filter = ('is_active',)

admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

Comment: Add a flag to the user model like is_verified and filter against that in the admin

Comment: I didn't understand.

Comment: In your modeladmin, override the queryset property to exclude users that are not active

Comment: ok so 2 days back you asked the same question. Answer will be same, override get_queryset method of admin, and filter with `is_active=True` or do it like @DovRine mentioned.

Comment: How to do it? I didn't understand. I searched but confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(UserAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
        return qs.filter(is_active=True)

    list_filter = ('is_active',)

admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```